# Would language difficulties be considered a valid excuse for a poor masters performance when applying for a PhD?

Tags: phd, application, language, language-exams

I recently completed a masters in a foreign country. I didn't know the language until the summer directly before, and foolishly thought that taking courses in a different language would be an interesting challenge. I was admitted to the course without needing to take any language competency exams. All lectures and learning material were in the foreign language, but we were allowed to write exams in my native language (which I did).

I absolutely bombed the first semester, achieving a mediocre result which is not great, and I felt that it was at least partially due to the language barrie. I managed to do better in my second semester. So I finished with a respectable grade but I don't know if it will be good enough for the competitive PhD programs that I was hoping to apply to next year. It is perhaps worth noting that I maintained excellent grades during my undergraduate years.

My question is; would those PhD programs be willing to view my second semester grades (which include my thesis) as more reflective of my potential than those of the first semester? In other words, are (self-inflicted) language difficulties considered to be mitigating circumstances?

Comment: In what part of the world will you be applying to doctoral programs?

Comment: I'm hoping to apply to Switzerland, Germany, France and the USA.

Comment: Pretty much impossible to predict how others will react. But you have a steep hill to climb. How to you create a prediction of success?

Comment: And are you fluent in German or will you be repeating the same issue?

Comment: Mathematical graduate programs in Germany (and indeed almost everywhere else) are English-language.

Comment: I don't see how this question can be answered unless you specify in the question the language of the PhD program.  The country does not always specify the language.  I don't think it's English in France.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It depends where you are and with whom you work. You will find English theses from France nowadays and at an institution with staff who speak good English, you may well undertake a PhD in English. BUT for everyday life, learning French is recommended and may even become essential. However this can be done as part of the degree. (Side note: I came to France as a post-doc, which was essentially in English for me, have since moved to industry. I initially got French classes from the Institute and nowadays get to speak more and more French in everyday life too, including work.)

Comment: @ggclip The PhD can be done in English, however most of the paid positions for PhD students in Germany include some TA-duty, for which often enough some fluency in German is required. Not that there aren't positions and of course scholarships that don't, but those will be harder to get.

Answer (score 3):

The good news is that you have a clear positive trajectory, and I'm assuming your undergraduate scores are quite good to get you accepted to the French MS program to begin with. In this case you have a high undergraduate GPA, and poor 1st semester MS GPA, and a good 2nd semester MS GPA.

This is something you should put into your cover letter. Straightforwardly acknowledge your difficulties as succinctly as you can, but phrase your 2nd semester "comeback" as overcoming a difficulty through hard work and perseverance.

A script might be: "I underestimated how difficult it would be to receive instruction in a language I didn't have a fluent grasp of, and my grades suffered in my first semester. However, through diligent effort to improve my French, as well as late nights studying my courses, I was able to gain good marks in my second semester. Therefore, while my GPA is not as high as I would like, I believe what I have learned in time management and self-study during the past year will help me overcome future difficulties that challenge any PhD student."

As to how potential admissions officers would react to such a statement is out of your control. If it were me and I was not in a top top program where I can afford to throw away 99% of the applications, I might keep you in the pile for further review.